Boundedness of solution to linear homogeneous second-order ODE
Consider a second-order linear homogeneous ODE, also known as the steady 1D Schrödinger equation
$$
x''(t)+g(t)x(t)=0,
$$
where $g(t)$ is a $C^1[0,+\infty)$ function and has a positive lower bound (exists $\lambda>0$ such that $g(t)\ge \lambda>0$ for all $t\ge0$). Assume initial data $(x(0),x'(0))$ is given.
I'm eager to know if there is any criteria, that for which kind of $g$, the solution $x$ will stay uniformly bounded in $[0,+\infty)$?
There is some simple case like $g(t)$ is monotone, which allows energy method to obtain boundedness of $x$. However, if $g'$ has infinitely many zeros, the solution is getting far more complicated.
Or at least, can we say for a specific choice of $g$, like $g(t)=1+\frac12\sin t$, the solution is unbounded? Indeed I'm seeking for examples of $g$ that may cause failure of boundedness and I just can't find any.
My Attempts:
First I try to apply the Prüfer transform that
$$(x(t),x'(t))=:r(t)e^{i\theta(t)}$$
a tedious argument says that if a $2\pi$-periodic $C^1$ function $\varphi(t)$ satisfies:
(1) $\theta(t)=-t+\varphi(t)$;
(2) $|\varphi'(t)\tan^2 \theta(t)|<+\infty$;
(3) $g(t)=\varphi'(t)\tan^2 \theta(t)-\varphi'(t)\ge \mu>-1$ for some real $\mu$;
(4) $0<|\int_0^{2\pi}\varphi'(t)\tan \theta(t)\mathrm{d}t|<+\infty$.
Then $g$ defined in (3) leads to unboundedness of solution $x$. Indeed, $x$ is given by (assume $x(0)=1$)
$$
x(t)=\exp[\int_0^{t}\varphi'(\tau)\tan \theta(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau]\cos\theta(t).
$$
From (4) one can expect that $x(2n\pi)\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. But I can't find any of such phase function $\theta$ and $\varphi$, and it seems the construction won't be trivial.
I've heard from an old celebrated theorem of Kneser (https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01444165), that in our setting of $g$, the solution $x(t)$ oscillate on $\mathbb R_+$, hence has infinitely many zeros (Indeed, to generate non-oscillating solutions one needs $\limsup_{t\to\infty} t^2g(t)<1/4$). Thus one cannot expect something like $x(t)\to\infty$ as $t\to\infty$ without taking any subsequence.
Several example plots drawn by Mathematica is given below. Here we always take $x(0)=1,x'(0)=0$.
This is example for $g=1+x^2$. The first plot is phase portrait, the second is simply the plot of $(x,x')(t)$, and the last one is logarithm of $r(t)$. In this example $x$ is ought to be bounded, since $g$ is monotonely increasing.

The second example is $g(t)=2+\sin t$. Surprisingly this solution seems to be bounded too.

And the last example I tried $g(t)=1+\frac12\sin t$. This seems to be unbounded, with radius exponentially increasing.

However, for the phenomenon in second and third example i've no idea how to give a rigorous derivation.

Hint: I would rewrite the system as a time-varying linear system in $\mathbb{R^2}$. The corresponding matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}
0 &1\
-g(t)& 0
\end{pmatrix}$.
For $g(t)\equiv 1$ the trajectories/orbits are closed circles. For $g(t)\equiv 2$ the trajectories are closed ellipses. Intuitively you can switch between the 2 values in such a way you can have unbounded trajectories. This will lead to a discontinuous periodic $g$, but you can approximate it with a $\mathcal{C}^1$ function without loosing the exploding behaviour.
